# Запись текста в конец файла, а не с новой строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

у меня имеется файл csv с примерно такими данными

```
;;;;;;57.67253850584151 63.065711945171756;"текст без переноса"
;;;;;;57.673070813642 63.067541643977;"текст
с переносом"
;;;;;;57.672613624414 63.068331554533;"текст
с переносом"
;;;;;;57.672155353661 63.070643618703;"текст без переноса"
```

мне надо чтобы строки начинающиеся с ";" записывали в новую строчку, а все что начинается не с ; дописывало в конец последней строки. Чтобы в итоге получилось вот так

```
;;;;;;57.67253850584151 63.065711945171756;"текст без переноса"
;;;;;;57.673070813642 63.067541643977;"текст с переносом"
;;;;;;57.672613624414 63.068331554533;"текст с переносом"
;;;;;;57.672155353661 63.070643618703;"текст без переноса"
```

Вряд ли мои наброски помогут, но вот мой код

```
with open(r"test.csv", "r") as source, open('output.txt', 'a') as destination:
    for line in source:
        if line.startswith(';'):
            destination.write(line)
        else:
            destination.write(line)
```

Буду благодарен любой помощи!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не хотите читать весь файл сразу, то можно так

```
not_first_line = False
with open(r"test.csv", "r") as source, open('output.txt', 'w') as destination:
    for line in source:
        if line.endswith('\n'):
            line = line[:-1]
        if not_first_line:
            if line.startswith(';'):
                destination.write('\n')
        else:
            not_first_line = True
        destination.write(line)
```

Флаг нужен для того, чтобы не добавлять перенос перед первой строкой.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо большое!

Comment: Вы можете избавиться от флага, если отдельно обработаете первую строку `line = source.readline()`, а затем можно использовать цикл по оставшимся строкам.

Answer (score 2):

Вот еще мое решение со стандартной библиотекой csv.

```
inport csv

with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvfile, open('output.txt', 'a') as destination:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='\"')
    test = tuple(spamreader)
    for row in test:
        destination.writelines(r.replace('\n', ' ') for r in row)
        destination.write('\n')
```